# Developing an Android app which can broadcast advertisements using Bluetooth Low Energy APIs

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an Android app which can broadcast advertisements using Bluetooth Low Energy APIs(Implemented in Android 5.0 with Nexus 6 & Nexus 9). I am putting my Nexus 9 in peripheral mode & it is broadcasting advertisements.

My question here is:
"Can every other android device with OS having Android 4.3 or greater receive advertisements without installing any third-party apps?"

I'm planning to develop Android app for peripheral mode only, but not for central mode for client devices.

Android 4.3 to 4.4 - Central mode(Device can receive advertisements)
Android 5.0 - Device can work in both central & peripheral mode.(can broadcast as well as receive advertisements).

Is it possible in any version of Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. There is no system tools / stock app that receive BLE advertisement (and display it out). You have to make it your own / use the existing third party app to achieve that.